# FRM-91191: runtime process: unable to allocate {0} bytes of memory; attempting to continue execution

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

> 

I am facing this problem whenever I am using Oracle Form Builder.

> FRM-91191: runtime process: unable to allocate {0} bytes of memory; attempting to continue execution

I have searched the net and in oracle docs it is showing that its happening due to the swap space problem.

Do anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when I tried to add a master-detail relationship in the Data Block Wizard. Not sure if this is when you were also seeing it but to stop it from happening to me, I unchecked the "auto-join data blocks" before clicking "Create Relationship" and the error stopped popping up.